# Same function for different sections - relative referencing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using relative references I am able to remove items which have been added to the list within a specfic part of the form. For example, by adding a requirement it can be deleted just from the requirement.

**My issue is two fold:**

1. Adding an item to references adds it to all three categories
2. When I try to add values to the other sections (qualifications) it says my input was blank.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sX6X/60/

```
var container = $('.copies'),
    value_src = $('#current'),
    maxFields = 10,
    currentFields = 1;

$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
      value_src.focus();
    if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
        if (currentFields < maxFields) {
            var value = value_src.val();
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
            currentFields++;
        } else {
            alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
        }
    } else {
        alert("You didn't enter anything");
    }

})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
        value_src.focus();
    $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

Is it possible to modify this code without repeating it for each section, by using relatively references such as "parent" for example. I want to use this same script for all three sections but have it so each list is independant.

I'm new to javascript so I was wondering if this is possible because I only managed to get it working on the delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this` to get the current element. In your case `this` refers to the button which was clicked.
The next step is to get the input box which belongs to the button. E.g. `$(this).prev();` like in this example:

```
$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
   var value_src = $(this).prev();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/62/

The same is also true for your appending part. Your are appending your html to all three elements which match `$('.copies')`. Instead you have to try to get there from `this`.

```
$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
   var value_src = $(this).prev();
   var copies = $(this).parent().prev();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/63/

Comment: Playing around with the example it still adds the item to every list, is this correct?

Comment: Ok, sorry to be a pain but now its a role reversal and the delete button doesn't work. I don't really understand why

Comment: This is because I didn't remove value_src from the delete callback: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/65/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a wrapping `div` to each section.

```
<div class="section">
    <h4>Requirements</h4>
    <div class="copies"></div>
    <div class="line">
        <input id="current" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Requirement" />
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="add" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do this:

```
var $section = $(this).closest(".section");

$(html).appendTo($section.find(".copies"));
```

This will add to just the related `.copies` element instead of to all `.copies` as your code does now.  A similar approach can be used for all other elements as well.

Comment: I have it this far with the wrapped section but when I try to put your javascript code in it fails. Can you show me where it should be going please? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sX6X/64/